# Small energy implies a lifting $\rho e^{i\theta}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde

Set $T^N$ the  $N$-dimensional torus and $u\in H^1(T^N,\mathbb{C})$. Can I say that if the energy$$\int_{T^N}|\nabla u|^2 +\frac12\int_{T^N}[1-|u|^2]^2$$ is small enough (let say lower than some $\epsilon>0$), then $|u|$ is close to one, and therefore $u$ admits a lifting $u=\rho e^{i\theta}$ on the torus?. In that case, when can I assure that $\theta\in H^1(T^N,\mathbb{C})$. Any idea or comment is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only in dimension $1$. In higher dimensions you can create a function with arbitrarily small energy that vanishes on an open set, after which you can change it a bit on that open set to make the argument $\theta$ behaving in a bad way.

Comment: But always, independently of the dimension, $|u|$ is close to $1$ if the energy is small, isnt it? The problem is that $\theta $ is not $H^1(T^N)$ when $N>1$. Am I right?

Comment: Only on a big set. On a small set $|u|$ can be as far from $1$ as you want.